# Javascript - Firefox Audio tag bug

Tags: javascript, audio

Does anyone noticed the bug in the audio tag on firefox? When you click on the "time bar" to go to determined point in the audio it doesnt take you to the correct minute and second.

I was playing Gorillaz - Feel Good Inc, which has 3 minutes and 40 seconds long, if i let the song play untill the end it ends at 3:40, but if i try to go near the end using the "time bar navigation", the audio extends and passes the song duration. This doesnt happen in Chrome.

I noticed this bug because I'm developing a library to implement the behaviour of an audio tag (play, volume, time bar etc...) so that we can customize the style of it.

Maybe it isnt a bug, but surely isnt how i expected the audio tag to work.

Have you noticed it? if it isnt a bug why did mozilla decided that it should be implemented this way?

There's an example

```html
<audio controls>
  <source type="audio/mp3" src="http://miguelpinto.x10.bz/drummachine/temp/Gorillaz_-_Feel_Good_Inc.mp3">
</audio>
```

It also happens when i set the currentTime property in javascript.

Comment: Have you tried to analyze the media file with ffmpeg (or a similar tool)? Maybe the duration is incorrect and you have to re-encode it.

Comment: I just analysed it and it seems ok, i downloaded the song from youtube it also shows the same time, and as i said, i tested in chrome and it worked just fine.